# Copy the highlighted green to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I managed to copy the cells in the same sheet. But that's not my primarily intention. I should be able to copy the highlighted cells to another worksheet like Sheet2 or Sheet3. How do I do that?

Below is what I have done for copying in the same sheet
[image: Click here to see image]

```
Sub copyHighlight()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long, i As Long, u As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If 2 > lr Then Exit Sub

        u = 2
        For i = 2 To lr
            If .Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
                .Cells(i, 1).Copy .Cells(u, "E")
                u = u + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good job on figuring out how to copy only certain cells, that stumps a lot of people.

Tiny change: add `Sheets("Sheet2")` as below:

```
Sub copyHighlight()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long, i As Long, u As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If 2 > lr Then Exit Sub

        u = 2
        For i = 2 To lr
            If .Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
                .Cells(i, 1).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(u, "E")
                u = u + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You're welcome :)  Of course, you could refer to the destination sheet other ways too, such as setting a `Worksheet` object somewhere else in the sub, or change it in the loop depending on cell value, etc

Comment: Great, useful info.. Appreciate that very much.. *thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very good, to achieve what you want, you only need reference to some other sheet, like shown below (I copied your code and added parts to make it work).

```
Sub copyHighlight()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim r As Long, i As Long, u As Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'here you set reference to another worksheet
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

With ws1
    lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If 2 > lr Then Exit Sub

    u = 2
    For i = 2 To lr
        If .Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
            .Cells(i, 1).Copy ws2.Cells(u, "E") 'NOTE, that here we used reference to another worksheet
            u = u + 1
        End If
    Next i
End With

Set ws1 = Nothing
Set ws2 = Nothing
End Sub
```